# If $n$ balls are placed at random into $n$ cells, find the probability that exactly one cell remains empty. (What am I doing wrong?)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If $n$ balls are placed at random into $n$ cells, find the probability that exactly one cell remains empty.

This is a fairly well-known problem from *Statistical Inference*. There are a number of posts regarding this problem, but I'd like to figure out where I'm going wrong.

The answer (apparently) is $c(n,2)n!/(n^n)$, where $c(n,k)$ is $n$ choose $k$. I came up with something different, and I can't seem to find a flaw in my reasoning.

Here's my approach:

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$ be the random vector for which $X_i = j$ when cell $i$ has $j$ balls in it (so $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$ and $j \in \{0, 1, ..., n\}$). Then $X$ follows a multinomial distribution, where
$$p_i = \frac{1}{n+1}, \qquad \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}, $$
since each $X_i$ can assume $1$ of the $n+1$ values in $\{0, 1, ..., n\}$ (with, I assume, equal probability). If we let $\alpha_i := P(\{X_i = 0\} \cap \{X_j \ne 0, i \ne j\})$, it is not too hard to see that $\alpha_1 = \cdots = \alpha_n$; and so our desired probability is
$$ \alpha := \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = n\alpha_1. $$
So, let's take a look at $\alpha_1$. We have that
$$\alpha_1 = P(X_1 = 0, X_2 \ne 0, ..., X_n \ne 0). $$
This looks like a pain, but if we consider the fact that there are $n-1$ tuples of the form
$$(0, j_2, ..., j_n), $$
where exactly one of the $j_2, ..., j_n$ is $2$ and the rest must be $1$s, it follows that
$$\alpha_1 = (n-1) \cdot \frac{n!}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n, $$
since $X$ is multinomial. Therefore,
$$ \alpha = \frac{n(n-1)n!}{2!}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n = \frac{n! n!}{2(n+1)^n(n-2)!} \ne  \frac{n! n!}{2n^n(n-2)!} = \frac{c(n,2)n!}{n^n}.$$
So, we see that my answer would agree with the stated answer if $p_i$ were $1/n$ instead of $1/(n+1)$. But, clearly, this cannot be the case... right?

Another thing that bothers me: Many answers to this problem begin by stating that "there are $n^n$ ways to distribute the balls among the cells." This is true if we our sampling from a collection of $n^n$ balls, not allowing any single cell to contain more than $n$ balls, and not allowing any cell to be empty; but this is not true in the given situation (as I understand it) since, e.g., the outcome $(n, n, ..., n)$ should not be allowed (as the components must sum to $n$)...

Comment: To see $n^n$:  for each of the $n$ balls, write down which cell it landed in.  There are $n$ choices for the first ball, $n$ independent choices for the second ball, ..., $n$ independent choices for the $n^\text{th}$ ball.

Comment: @EricTowers For one, that approach assumes no cell can be empty (which, clearly, we must be allowing for). That approach also assumes sampling with replacement, which (by the way the problem is stated) doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: You have it exactly backwards.  We aren't producing a label for each cell, indicating which ball it contains.  We are labeling each ball by the cell it lands in.  All labels can be the same (all balls in one cell).  There is no sampling, so there is no sampling with replacement.

Comment: @EricTowers Fair enough. I suppose my issue is that I'm viewing each outcome as the distribution of the (indistinguishable) balls among the (distinguishable) cells, rather than viewing the experiment as a sequence of (independent) trials. Nevertheless, I can't seem to figure out how I am supposed to have known that just based on how the problem is stated...

Comment: Notice I'm not asserting distinguishable balls, merely that each ball has a cell.  We are always free to order the balls, as long as we remember to disregard our artificial ordering by the time we are finished.  (This is analogous to the freedom to pick any basis you like in linear algebra to compute something.  The result exists without the basis, but the choice of basis makes that result computable.)

Comment: Where is the constraint $\sum_i X_i = n$?  I've tried parsing your specification of a multinomial distribution repeatedly.  I keep getting hung up on the bizarrity that $\sum_i p_i \neq 1$ and I'm hoping that this bizarrity is related to some sneaky way of requiring that there are exactly $n$ total balls among the cells.

Comment: @EricTowers Ah, that's true: my $p_i$ do not sum to 1... which is, indeed, a problem. As I was viewing it, the $X_i$ are the number of balls in cell $i$ after having placed all $n$ balls. So, let's take $n=3$. Then, e.g.,  $(X_1, X_2, X_3) = (2,0,1)$ indicates that 2 balls were placed in cell 1, and 1 ball was placed in cell 3. Similarly, $(X_1, X_2, X_3) = (0,3,0)$ indicates that all 3 balls were placed in cell 2. And so on. Since there are only 3 balls, we must always have $X_1 + X_2 + X_3 = 3$; hence the constraint.

Comment: I agree that this constraint should exist.  I don't see that it is implemented in the specification of your multinomial distribution.  Your "with, I assume, equal probability" has me very worried, since it seems to allow excessively many total balls.

Comment: Oh, I see (I think...). So, $p_i$ is the probability that (after all $n$ balls have been distributed) cell $i$ has $j$ balls in it. Since cell $i$ can have 0 balls in it, or 1 ball in it, or ..., or $n$ balls in it, there are $n+1$ possibilities, and they are all (I assume) equally probable. I think that this, indeed, might be the problem because these are not equally probable since, e.g., there is only one outcome in which, say, $X_1 = n$ (since all other cells are empty) but there is more than outcome when, say, $X_1 = n-1$ (since the 1 remaining ball can be in any of the remaining cells).